# Convergence in distribution of $\sqrt{n}\cdot(\ln(2\cdot \bar{X_n}) - \ln(\theta))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working through the following:

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed variables, with $X_n \sim \mathcal{U}[0,\theta]$. Show that $\sqrt{n}\cdot(\ln(2\cdot \bar{X_n}) - \ln(\theta))$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\frac{1}{3})$

Now, so far I've tried using the central limit theorem, by multiplying and dividing by $\frac{\bar{X_n} - \frac{\theta}{2}}{\sigma}$, with $\sigma := V(X_1) = V(X_n) \ (\forall n)$. However, I'm left with the factor

$$
\frac{ln(2\cdot \bar{X_n}) - \ln(\theta)}{\bar{X_n} - \frac{\theta}{2}}\cdot \sigma
$$

which I haven't been able to effectively control. I'm almost certain this involves the CLT, so maybe I'm just making the expression "appear" the wrong way, i.e. maybe I should work with the expression inside the logarithm first.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you specify what $\ln(2\bar{X_n})$ is?

Comment: Are you familiar with delta method?

Comment: @Shashi By $\bar{X_n}$ I mean $\frac{X_1 + \dots X_n}{n}$.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan no, unfortunately I'm unaware of the method. In fact, I'm taking my first class in probabilty theory at the moment, so I don't have much of a "toolkit" built yet.

Comment: It's useful in analyzing asymptotic distribution of transformed random sequences. Take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545015/show-that-sqrtn-ln2-overlinex-n-ln-theta-overset-mathcald-to

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Cool. Thanks a lot!